# Ajax multiple checkboxes displaying dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display different content on a webpage which is request by a user via checkboxes.

I have a php sidebar displaying multiple checkboxes.

```
<label><input id="<?php echo $side_oq['Sidebar_Content']; ?>" type="checkbox"><?php echo $side_oq['Sidebar_Content']; ?></label>
```

As I am not that familiar with JQuery and Ajax, I did some digging and made a single request work.

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#A1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        var check = $(this).attr("id");
         $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: check})
    }else{
        $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: NULL})
    }
});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#A2').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        var check = $(this).attr("id");
         $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: check})
    }else{
        //$('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: 0})
    }
});
});
```

**PHP**

```
//sideRead.php
$side_content_sql="SELECT *
                       FROM Sidebar
                        WHERE Sidebar_Level='".$_POST['postcheck']."'";
$side_content_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $side_content_sql);
$side_content_oq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($side_content_query);
```

1. Problem

If I uncheck the box nothing happens (as I have not implemented it) but I don't really have an idea how its done.

//edit
If I try to put "NULL" in #A1 nothing changes.

If I pass the else-statement from #A2 the sql-query will be empty and I can catch that and display nothing but there will also be a fatal error

2. Problem

If I use the posted ajax code twice and change  *$('#A1').change(function(){*   to  *$('#A2').change(function(){*  #A2 "overwrites" #A1 but if both are checked I want to display both

//edit 2

I changed the Ajax code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sideRead_Level').each(function() {  
    $(this).change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            var check = $(this).attr("id");
             $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: check});
        }else{
            $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: null});
        }
    });
});
});
```

Now it is working for every checkbox but the content is still not kept if I mark multiple.

Secondly, the deselection still makes some problems.

1. If I deselect a checkbox I get a Type Error : document.getElementById(...) is null
2. Handling the else-statement is still not working. I get a sql-query like
   "FROM Sidebar WHERE Sidebar_Level=''" which results in a "Recoverable fatal error"

If I try to catch the else-statement in php, such as:

```
if(!is_null($_POST['postcheck']){//do sql}
else{//print nothing}
```

the complete php script doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Since you don't have any logic related to problem 1 in your question (as per the *//Not Ready*), can you show us the logic that you were having an issue with for problem 2?

Comment: Deselecting a checkbox is just unchecking it.  I'm not understanding your comment related to that.  My desire to see your implementation of `A2` revolves around this line of code. `$('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: check})`.  If you left that the same for both change handlers, they would both be stepping on each other as that lookup is a global lookup and will find all element matching that class.

Comment: Concerning Problem 1:
There is no implementation because I dont get how "deselect" the elements again

if I do

else{
$('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: 0})
}

well the sql will be empty and nothing will be shown if I catch it in a if{}else{} in php but I get a fatal error :(

Concerning Problem 2:
I think I have to get all IDs into an array load that array to the php document and then add that to the sql query.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#A2').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
   var check = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: check})
  }else{
   //$('.home_textbox_1').load("sideRead.php", {postcheck: 0})
  }
 });
});

Yeah this is it for #A2 (as you expected)

Comment: Please editor your question with the extra logic.  It is very hard to read in the comments and is more appropriate for the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenience but I am new to stackoverflow so I didn't know that it is displayed in such a way. Hope you can understand it a bit better now in the edited post

Comment: Regarding your marking multiple not keeping data, that is because you are setting `$('.home_textbox_1')` for both the A1 and A2 change.  They will be overlaying each other with those global lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is still not working perfectly concerning what I want to achieve, however, it might help other beginners to get a better understanding of using checkboxes with php, ajax and jquery.

At this point, special thanks to Taplar for your help.

[The current toggle menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVUhQ.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('input.sideButton').change(function() {       
    var checked = []; 
    $("input[name='sideShow']").each(function() {   
        $(this).change(function() {
            $("input[name='sideShow']:checked").each(function (){
                checked.push($(this).val());    
                $('.home_textbox').load("example.php", {postcheck: checked});
            });
            checked = []; 
        });
    });
});
});
```

In my code there are still some further problems which I guess result from other things, however, if I check the textboxes the array pushed to php looks most of the time like (example):

- Array ( [0] => A1 )
- Array ( [0] => A1 [1 ] => A2 [2] => B1 )

The deselection also works most of the time (sometimes random stuff happens, though) except if only one element is selected, eg *Array ( [0] => A1 )*. The array then never changes into an empty array.

I hope someone can use this or might have further thoughts concerning the topic.